# How to resolve freeze on keyring after upgrading Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, 18.04, keyrings, gnome-keyring

After upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04, my system became sluggish after restart.

I have auto login enabled, so that still works, yet any action afterwards was very slow. During boot, error reporting ran and asked me to send the error report, yet on sending I started to type in my password yet the window would freeze so I was unable to do anything further. I could only reboot (Magic REISUB)

(This will happen for any application with stored passwords, e.g. Chrome).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should probably file a bug report on Launchpad regarding this issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your [storage device is healthy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077#528077) A failing drive will often result in laggy behavior such as you describe.

Comment: This may be related to https://askubuntu.com/q/1029604/32792 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I could still use my terminal before the keyring notification came up and also use sudo with password.

As a workaround I hence changed my password to a very short one, e.g. `f`:

```
 sudo passwd MY_USER
```

Then I could enter my password on time for the keyring unlocking, restoring my system to a useable state.

I also switched from gdm3 to lightdm as I would get login freezes.