# Updated to 18.04, PC freezes before the login screen (Ubuntu logo)

Tags: boot, 18.04

My PC freezes before the login screen (Ubuntu logo); if I select RECOVERY MODE and resume boot everything goes well. I suspect a problem with the graphics driver.

Comment: look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029604/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-hangs-on-login-screen/1030771#1030771

Answer (score 13):

Finally I was able to solve the issue by uncommenting the line `#WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 18.10 as well.

Comment: This was a lifesaver! Worked for me too. Thanks

Comment: This solved my problem too. Should be set as the chosen answer. But sadly these kinds of things make me still not trust Ubuntu and pushes me to back up my whole virtual machine before any update... What will happen with the next update, is it going to consider this change, is this consider by Ubuntu team as a bug ? Who knows...

Comment: Works with 18.04

Comment: Anyone knows why this works?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps i can supplement the answer to @Vishesh Gautam and @Marcelo4k:

In the ArchWiki page on GNOME desktop environment, it is stated that ["the default display is Wayland instead of Xorg."](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME) Hence, there maybe problem if the default display server is Xorg. It is noted that [Ubuntu 18.04 default display server is Xorg.](https://www.secjuice.com/wayland-vs-xorg/) This explains the issue if /etc/gdm3/custom.conf has wayland display server enabled.

@Marcelo4k has successfully troubleshoot the problem by uncommenting the line `#WaylandEnable=false`, so Wayland display server is disabled and Xorg will be the active display server. This is noted in Fedora documentation as [the first step to disable Wayland to run Gnome on Xorg](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/). It further recommended to add a new line under [daemon] section:

```
DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop
```

The above recommendation is valid if the result of gdm3 is active (running) using systemctl status:

```
systemctl status gdm3
```

However if gdm3 is disabled and lightdm is enabled perhaps due to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04. Then lightdm maybe active (running) instead.

So if lightdm is inactive, do as what @Vishesh Gautam has suggested by running `sudo start lightdm` or running as below to start light display manager:

```
systemctl start lightdm
```

However these applies only to Gnome desktop environment. If you have other desktop environments matched with other display managers, you have to consult relevant documentations to your respective desktop environment and display managers. Again, ArchWiki provide a good introduction to [Display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager) and they give a relevant list on how to match which desktop environment to which display manager.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is applicable for lightdm.*

Most probably the login display manager is not starting, try starting the Lightdm manually  (if you haven't changed it, i.e Default) from TTY by the following command : `sudo start lightdm`

> A display manager presents the user with a login screen. A session
>   starts when a user successfully enters a valid combination of username
>   and password.

PS : If you don't know, you can access TTY by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1/2/3/4 at the freeze point you're referring to and then login with username and password.

Comment: Thanks, if freezes in "Started User Manager for UID 123" and cannot move on.

Comment: Exit TTY by CTRL+ALT+F7 after execution of above command, and see if it helps.

Comment: It freezes at some point of the now verbose boot. But if I go through RECOVERY MODE and resume boot I get the graphical login screen (I suppose is light dm)

Comment: This might help : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/542012/ubuntu-14-10-booting-problems-no-login-screen/542490#542490

Comment: Isn't gdm the default in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the post says *Updated* to 18.04, so I posted my answer by keeping in mind that the Display manager hasn't been changed to gdm. As I updated my system too and it didn't change my display manager lightdm to gdm.

Answer (score -1):

A combination of the advice here solved the same issue for me on Ubuntu 19.10.

When the system started and hung with the mouse pointer at the bottom right of the screen, I was able to move it but there was no login window.

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to start a console session in TTY2, logged in and opened the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. There I uncommented the line `#WaylandEnable=false` (by deleting the `#` at the beginning of the line)

I then typed `reboot` and tadaaaaaa!