# system freeze after login in 18.04 gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

I recently upgraded my system to Ubuntu 18.04. 
After I login in `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu on Wayland` mode the system freeze. I can move my mouse. I can switch to tty3 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. But I could not actually click on any icon or button. Neither can I open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

However, If I log in with `Unity shell`, everything seems fine.
I have tried the solutions in following posts but did not work.

- Install Nvidia drive and turn off secure boot.[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and [Freeze after login Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030060/freeze-after-login-ubuntu-18-04)
- Switch between `lightdm` and `gdm3` [Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome hangs on login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029604/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-hangs-on-login-screen)

My laptop is Dell XPS 15.
`Linux XPS 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Please let me know if there are any ways to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to use gnome-shell. After I removed all the gnome extensions, the freeze issue was solved.
You can try to remove all the gnome extensions from `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and reboot.